# RESTful API, C++restSDK, JSON in C++

Tags: c++, json, rest, c++11

I am trying to use THIS RESTful API: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

To do this, I am using THIS C++ SDK: https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk

The Binance API returns everything as JSON, which is where I think my issue lies.

My code is here: https://pastebin.com/SeBAxvA0

I think the error is here in this function (commented as well in pastebin):

```
void print_test(json::value const & value){
    if(!value.is_null()){
        //I am doing something wrong here I'm pretty sure.
        auto response = value[L"responseData"];
       //"responseData" is probably not what should be here I think?
        auto results = response[L"serverTime"];
        wcout << results.as_integer() << endl;
    }
}
```

Basically, I am trying to just test out this API by doing a simple GET method for the server time from the Binance API. According to the Binance documentation:

```
Check server time
GET /api/v1/time
Test connectivity to the Rest API and get the current server time.

Weight: 1

Parameters: NONE

Response:
{
  "serverTime": 1499827319559
}
```

So I would like to do a GET request for that JSON, and then have my C++ program output the value of serverTime. When I try to run my code as is, I get an error saying:

```
error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type
  'const json::value'
    auto response = value[L"responseData"];
```

However, I am following along with an example from the C++restSDK found here: 
http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2013/08/02/cpp-rest-sdk-in-visual-studio-2013/

I think my issue has something to do with the two lines under the comment I made on line 45 in my pastebin. Presumably, I am assigning the wrong values to one or both of the variables under that line. I know this is a pretty specific help request, but does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to get the value of serverTime to display?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] *in the question itself*.

Comment: I gave the error I am getting, the lines where I think the error is, what I think the error is caused by, the resources I am using, the problem I am attempting to solve, and 2 relevant documentations pertaining to the issue, what do I need to add?

Comment: ok - code is long so I did not want to post the whole thing and make a massive post -- I edited in the specific function I think the error is in and have the error posted as well, does that work?

Comment: Assuming people familiar with those libraries (i.e. not me) can find out or know what `json::value` is, this looks fine now. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue on my own after much digging :) 
Error was in this function and it is now fixed with this code:

```
void print_test(json::value const & value){
    if(!value.is_null()){
        json::value test = value;
        cout << test["serverTime"] << endl;
    }
}
```